# pandas: Keep only top n values and set others to 0

Tags: python, pandas

In a pandas dataframe, for every row, I want to keep only the top N values and set everything else to 0.
I can iterate through the rows and do it but I am sure python/pandas can do it elegantly in a single line.

For e.g.: for N = 2

```
Input:
A   B   C   D
4   10  10  6
5   20  50  90
6   30  6   4
7   40  12  9

Output:
A   B   C   D
0   10  10  0
0   0   50  90
6   30  6   0
0   40  12  0
```

Comment: Please explain the output. How is it that for column `A`, you are replacing `7` with 0 and retaining `6`?

Comment: @MayankPorwal Each **row** seems to only keep the largest 2 values (or more if there is a tie)

Comment: Yes, that's right. Will edit to make it clear.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Using [`rank`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rank.html) with parameters `axis=1` and `method='min'` and `ascending=False` as:

```
N = 2
df = df.mask(df.rank(axis=1, method='min', ascending=False) > N, 0)
```

Or using [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with [`pd.DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html) which is faster than `mask` method:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.where(df.rank(axis=1,method='min',ascending=False)>N, 0, df),
                  columns=df.columns)
```

---

```
print(df)
   A   B   C   D
0  0  10  10   0
1  0   0  50  90
2  6  30   6   0
3  0  40  12   0
```

## **Explanation :**

**Step 1:**
First we need to find what are the 2 smallest numbers in the row and also if there is a duplicate that need to be taken account. So, using `axis=1` ranks across rows and duplicate values will be taken care by `method='min'` and `ascending = False`:

```
print(df.rank(axis=1, method='min', ascending=False))
     A    B    C    D
0  4.0  1.0  1.0  3.0
1  4.0  3.0  2.0  1.0
2  2.0  1.0  2.0  4.0
3  4.0  1.0  2.0  3.0
```

**Step 2:** Second we need to filter where the values is greater than (N) as per condition and then change those values using [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html):

```
print(df.rank(axis=1, method='min', ascending=False) > N)
       A      B      C      D
0   True  False  False   True
1   True   True  False  False
2  False  False  False   True
3   True  False  False   True

print(df.mask(df.rank(axis=1, method='min', ascending=False) > N, 0))
   A   B   C   D
0  0  10  10   0
1  0   0  50  90
2  6  30   6   0
3  0  40  12   0
```

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 added explanation check it.

Comment: This did not work when I applied it to my full data set. You could check with more number of columns.

Comment: @NikhilUtane Can you show the sample data for which it fails.

Comment: Sure, I have copied a portion of sample data [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1djkW7sB-AN9jTC1o3y4THtsyYHIwWnhX)

Comment: @NikhilUtane I cannot access it. Check this `df.mask(df.rank(axis=1, method='dense', ascending=False) > N, 0)`, if didn't work. I will delete the answer.

Comment: Check now. It should be accessible.

Comment: It almost worked. It is much faster than the other solution. However when the top 5 values were like these, 194, 158, 158, 143, 143. It picked all 5 instead of the first 3. The other solution picks the top 3 correctly. Thanks.

Comment: @NikhilUtane For that case other solutions also giving all 5 values when `N = 5`.

Comment: When N=5, it is fine. It should not give 5 when N=3.

Comment: @NikhilUtane Check this one last time `df.mask(df.rank(axis=1, method='min', ascending=False) > N, 0)`

Comment: Yes, this works like a charm, almost instantaneously while the other solution takes about 10 secs.. Pls update the original answer.

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
N = 2
df = df.where(df.apply(lambda x: x.isin(x.nlargest(N)), axis=1), 0)
print (df)
   A   B   C   D
0  0  10  10   0
1  0   0  50  90
2  6  30   6   0
3  0  40  12   0
```

Or:

```
import heapq
N = 2
df = df.where(df.apply(lambda x: x.isin(heapq.nlargest(N, x)), axis=1), 0)
print (df)
   A   B   C   D
0  0  10  10   0
1  0   0  50  90
2  6  30   6   0
3  0  40  12   0
```

Comment: Not quite the right output. Index 2 is `6 30 6 0`  in OPs expected output

Answer (score 1):

Use nlargest to get N largest numbers:

```
df.mask(~df.apply(lambda x: x.isin(x.nlargest(2)), axis=1), 0)
```

Outpu:

```
    A   B   C   D
0   0   10  10  0
1   0   0   50  90
2   6   30  6   0
3   0   40  12  0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`scipy.stats.rankdata`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rankdata.html) via [`np.apply_along_axis`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.apply_along_axis.html), and feed to [`pd.DataFrame.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.where.html):

```
from scipy.stats import rankdata

df[:] = df.where(np.apply_along_axis(rankdata, 1, df, method='max') > 2, 0)

print(df)

   A   B   C   D
0  0  10  10   0
1  0   0  50  90
2  6  30   6   0
3  0  40  12   0
```

#### Performance benchmarking

[`pd.DataFrame.rank`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rank.html) is most efficient of solutions below; `apply` + `lambda` perform worst.

```
from scipy.stats import rankdata
from heapq import nlargest

df = pd.concat([df]*100, ignore_index=True)

%timeit df.mask(df.rank(axis=1, method='min', ascending=False) > 2, 0)       # 2.23 ms per loop
%timeit df.where(np.apply_along_axis(rankdata, 1, df, method='max') > 2, 0)  # 45 ms per loop
%timeit df.where(df.apply(lambda x: x.isin(nlargest(2, x)), axis=1), 0)      # 92.4 ms per loop
%timeit df.mask(~df.apply(lambda x: x.isin(x.nlargest(2)), axis=1), 0)       # 274 ms per loop
```