# How to keep the only the top N values in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

It is pandas/Dataframe, for every row, I want to keep only the top N (N=3) values and set others to `nan`,

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = np.array([['','day1','day2','day3','day4','day5'],
                ['larry',1,4,4,3,5],
                ['gunnar',2,-1,3,4,4],
                ['tin',-2,5,5, 6,7]])
                
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data[1:,1:],
                  index=data[1:,0],
                  columns=data[0,1:])
print(df)
```

output is

```
       day1 day2 day3 day4 day5
larry     1    4    4    3    5
gunnar    2   -1    3    4    4
tin      -2    5    5    6    7
```

I want to get

```
       day1 day2 day3 day4 day5
larry   NaN    4    4  NaN    5
gunnar  NaN  NaN    3    4    4
tin     NaN    5  NaN    6    7
```

Similar to [pandas: Keep only top n values and set others to 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53169397/pandas-keep-only-top-n-values-and-set-others-to-0), but I need to keep only N highest available values, otherwise the average is not correct

For the result above I want to keep first `5` only

Comment: The data you provided has `dtype=object` for most columns. This could create issues for sorting and other manipulations later on, but not sure if this is just a problem with the sample or your real data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is another way using `df.rank` on `axis=1` , we reverse the columns and calculate the rank since on a duplicate you want to retain the first value.

```
df[df.astype(float).iloc[:,::-1].rank(1,'first').ge(3)]
```

---

```
       day1 day2 day3 day4 day5
larry   NaN    4    4  NaN    5
gunnar  NaN  NaN    3    4    4
tin     NaN    5  NaN    6    7
```

---

however as @Allolz rightly directed, for a general usecase based on the shape of the df, one can use:

```
N=3
n = df.shape[1]-N+1
df[df.astype(float).iloc[:,::-1].rank(1,'first').ge(n)]
```

Comment: for my real case, the second using `shape` works

Answer (score 6):

You can use `np.unique` to sort and find the 5th largest value, and use `where`:

```
uniques = np.unique(df)

# what happens if len(uniques) < 5?
thresh = uniques[-5]
df.where(df >= thresh)
```

Output:

```
        day1  day2  day3  day4  day5
larry    NaN   4.0     4     3     5
gunnar   NaN   NaN     3     4     4
tin      NaN   5.0     5     6     7
```

---

**Update**: On the second look, I think you can do:

```
df.apply(pd.Series.nlargest, n=3,axis=1).reindex(df.columns, axis=1)
```

Output:

```
        day1  day2  day3  day4  day5
larry    NaN   4.0   4.0   NaN   5.0
gunnar   NaN   NaN   3.0   4.0   4.0
tin      NaN   5.0   NaN   6.0   7.0
```

Comment: can u give more complete one, I am new to this. two errors 1. day1 is missing, 2. `nlargest` is not correct

Comment: @LarryCai see updates. What do you mean `nlargest` is not correct? I see it matches your expected output, even on duplicates ones?

Comment: TypeError: Cannot use method 'nlargest' with dtype object

Comment: also I need to reset them to int instead of float

Answer (score 4):

To keep, for every row, the top 3 values you can use:

```py
df = (df * df.astype(float).apply(lambda x: x.isin(x.nlargest(3)), axis=1)).replace('', np.nan)
```

You can migrate `nlargest`'s parameter into a variable if needed.

Output:

```
        day1 day2 day3 day4 day5
larry    NaN    4    4  NaN    5
gunnar   NaN  NaN    3    4    4
tin      NaN    5    5    6    7
```

Comment: how to keep only first 5 for `tin`

Comment: For `tin` the third highest value is present twice, this is why both occurrences are kept.

Comment: one key problem of this question is that how can I keep first one, do u have solution for it? so I can keep total N values for each row

Answer (score 4):

`stack`, `sort`, keep the top 3 per row with a `groupby`, and then `unstack`. We need a `mergesort` to ensure we always keep the first value per row in the case of ties.  Reindex ensures we have all the original columns if there are no largest values in any of the rows for that column.

If you require `Int` in the end, the best you can do is `'Int64'`, pandas nullable-integer dtype.

```
# df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric)  # To make numeric, not object. 

N = 3
(df.stack()
   .sort_values(ascending=False, , kind='mergesort')
   .groupby(level=0).head(N)
   .unstack()
   .reindex(df.columns, axis=1)
   .astype('Int64'))
```

---

```
        day1  day2  day3  day4  day5
larry   <NA>     4     4  <NA>     5
gunnar  <NA>  <NA>     3     4     4
tin     <NA>     5  <NA>     6     7
```

---

Here are some timings vs the number of rows, and proof that these three methods are equivalent (before any type-casting). @anky's solution is very fast and simple.

```
import perfplot
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


def alollz_stack(df, N=3):
    return (df.stack()
              .sort_values(ascending=False, kind='mergesort')
              .groupby(level=0).head(N)
              .unstack()
              .reindex(df.columns, axis=1))
    
def quang_nlargest(df, N=3):
    return df.apply(pd.Series.nlargest, n=N, axis=1).reindex(df.columns, axis=1)

def anky_rank(df, N=3):
    return df[df.iloc[:,::-1].rank(1,'first').ge(df.shape[1]-N+1)]
    

perfplot.show(
    setup=lambda n: pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 100, (n, 5)),
                                 columns=[f'col{i}' for i in range(1,6)]), 
    kernels=[
        lambda df: alollz_stack(df),
        lambda df: quang_nlargest(df),
        lambda df: anky_rank(df)],
    labels=['Stack', 'Apply_Nlargest', 'Rank'],
    n_range=[2 ** k for k in range(18)],
    equality_check=lambda x,y: np.allclose(x,y, equal_nan=True),
    xlabel='N_rows'
)
```

[image]